# Swift - Display phone caller name into the app

Tags: ios, swift, contacts, phone-call, callkit

I need to display into my app the name of the person once I receive a phone call.
How can I make it? Any idea? I searched for days for an answer on the net but noting.
Please help me!

Thanks to all support!!

Comment: Short answer, you can't - Your app cannot access any details of GSM calls for privacy reasons.

Comment: And why wearables devices can access calls and messages?

Comment: They would implement the ANCS protocol to receive the notifications and call details via Bluetooth  The user has to pair the device before it has this access, so it is assumed that the user has decided to trust that device